# Align Images - Android

Tags: android, imageview

I would like the first image to be 20px away from the left side of the screen and the right image to be 20px away from the right side of the screen and have tried various things but cant get it to work.

Here is mycode:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hello_moon, parent, false);

    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.l1);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());

    ImageView imageL = new ImageView(getActivity());
    imageL.setImageResource(R.drawable.bell_dl_256);
    imageL.setScaleX((float) 0.50);
    imageL.setScaleY((float) 0.5);

    ImageView imageR = new ImageView(getActivity());
    imageR.setImageResource(R.drawable.bell_dr_256);
    imageR.setScaleX((float) 0.5);
    imageR.setScaleY((float) 0.5);

    tr.addView(imageL);
    tr.addView(imageR);
    tl.addView(tr);

    return v;
```

Comment: use a piddingLeft and PaddingRight on the tablerow

Comment: also try "margin" property.

Comment: Thanks that is great, how would I align my images Left and Right respectively so they will line up against each margin?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) instead of TableLayout and `android:layout_alignParentRight` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft` [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) on child elements, ImageViews in your case. To make your ImageView move away from the edge just use the margins `android:layout_marginLeft` and `android:layout_marginRight` on your ImageView.

Further, it is recommended that you use dp instead of px. px is an absolute measure and dp is a relative measure of the pixel density of the screen. The second is best suited to screens with different sizes.